# Object not being passed with @Input decorator Angular2

Tags: angular

When getting data from a subscription, my data is not being binded to my local variable.

I have two components, and a service. The parent component invokes a method from a service to do to an http get, the get includes a user object which I need to bind.
However, when console.logging the object outside the subscription it appears undefined.

Here is my code:

Parent Component:

```
selectedUser : User;
  onUserRowSelect(event): void {
    this.router.navigate(['../childComponent'], { relativeTo: this.route });

    this.formService.getUser(event.data.USER_ID).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result); // <-- Object is logged properly.
      this.selectedUser = result; // Assigning the local @Input variable to the result
    });
  }
```

Child Component:

```
  @Input() selectedUser : User;

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.selectedUser); // Returns undefined.
      }
```

Service with Http:

```
getUser(id: number): Observable<User> {
    const _url = 'myURL/getuser/' + id;
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('X-Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('X-AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get(_url, options)
        .map(response => {
            const responseAsObject = response.json();
            this.myUser = responseAsObject;
            return responseAsObject;
        });
}
```

So my issue lies with selectedUser appearing undefined in the child component even after adding @input decorator to the variable.

Parent HTML:

```
    <div>
    <div class="row-md-6">
        <nb-card title="List of Users">
            <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="source" (userRowSelect)="onUserRowSelect($event)"></ng2-smart-table>
        </nb-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child HTML:

```
<div id="top">
<nb-card>
    <nb-card-header>Update User</nb-card-header>
    <nb-card-body header="Update User">
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <form [formGroup]="complexForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(complexForm.value)">
                    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!complexForm.controls['username'].valid}">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="username" class="form-control" id="username" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['username']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!complexForm.controls['group_id'].valid}">
                        <label>Group ID</label>
                        <div class="row" *ngIf="roles.length">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup" name="group_id" (change)="onChange($event)" class="form-control" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['group_id']"
                                    data-width='200px'>
                                    <option [ngValue]="role.GROUP_ID" *ngFor="let role of roles">
                                        {{role.NAME}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="fname" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['fname']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>User ID</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="ID" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['USER_ID']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="lname" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['lname']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Organization</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="organization" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['organization']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="phone" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['phone']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Creation Date</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="creationDate" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['creation_date']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Login</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="lastLogin" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['last_login']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!complexForm.controls['status'].valid}">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <div class="row" *ngIf="statuses.length">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" name="stasus" (change)="onChange($event)" class="form-control" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['status']"
                                    data-width='500px'>
                                    <option [ngValue]="status.STATUS" *ngFor="let status of statuses">
                                        {{status.STATUS_DESC}}
                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Logged In</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="loggedIn" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['logged_in']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password Bad Tries</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="pwdBadTries" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['pwd_badtries']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="title" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['title']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="email" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['email']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>User Expiry in Days</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="userExpiryInDays" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['user_expiry_in_days']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!complexForm.controls['restricted_ip'].valid}">
                        <label>Restricted IP</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="restrictedIp" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['restricted_ip']">
                        <div *ngIf="complexForm.controls['restricted_ip'].hasError('pattern') && complexForm.controls['restricted_ip'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">Not a valid IP Address.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password Expiry Date</label>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="pwdExpdate" class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="complexForm.controls['pwd_expdate']">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" value="update" [disabled]="!complexForm.valid" class="btn btn-success">Update User</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" value="delete" class="btn btn-success" (click)="confirmDelete()">Delete User</button>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" value="delete" class="btn btn-success" (click)="getNewPassword()">Set Password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Comment: Use `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngOnInit`.

Comment: ngOnChanges is never invoked, its not logging in console.

Comment: Before the `ngOnInit` the first `ngOnChanges` has to be invoked. See here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks Did you use `implements OnChanges`? Try to `console.log` something else to check (`console.log(42);` for example).

Comment: Yes I did add the implements properly, does it matter where its placed in the code you mean?

Comment: No. Have you tried `ngOnChanges() { console.log(42); }`?

Comment: Didn't log anything.

Comment: What tag does the child have in parent? Unclear, I can't see it, and nowhere do you have marked the input in the child tag?

Answer (score 0):

Really old question but the answer here is the input does not exist on the constructor, but it will exist eventually. Use ngOnInit to see the inputs.

```
class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(changes.selectedUser);
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your onInit in child is executing too soon. Add an ngOnChanges method and log all the changes. You should see that as it becomes available in the parent later on, it will get updated on the child too.

```
class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes.selectedUser);
  }
  ...
}
```

Note that you don't need the ngOnChanges to get them. This is only if you want to react explicitly. You can simply prepare your component to work without the selectedUser before it becomes available (or hide it with, say, ngIf).

Comment: odd, ngOnChanges is never invoked. I can't console log within it.

Comment: Can you post your entire childcomponent (remove any restricted or unnecessary code one by one until just before the error dies)? It's strange that it doesn't fire onChanges.

Comment: only the constructor should fire before the data is there. logging in the ngOnInit should be fine

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Proof that you're wrong: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-init-changes?file=app/app.component.ts
It would be true if the initial selectedUser was set synchronously. But he's making the call to backend for users.

Comment: but that isnt proof, thats running in a sandbox, to test properly you would need to make an angular app which, when tested, would be able to grab the data passed in the `@Input()`'s within the ngOnInit

Comment: Of course it is! Doesn't matter where it runs. You can click "open in new window" there, and the code runs the same. You can click "Export" and you get a whole angular app. Download it, npm install and run it - same result.
But ultimately, it's not about a running code. It is about proof of concept.